# How to fix ServiceStack incompatibility with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack, visual-studio-2017

I tried to add ServiceStack to my ASP.NET MVC Web App project, by going in
Project > Add NuGet Packages and installing de ServiceStack Package, but I get this error:

*One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win-x86).
Incompatible packages: 5
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ProteinTracker'.*

I'am using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac OS, and I'am new to the IDE and the Microsoft's Frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of [ServiceStack .NET Core packages have a .Core suffix](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#net-core-servicestack-packages) so you would need to add a reference to `ServiceStack.Core`.

Alternatively you can also start with one of [ServiceStack's .NET Core Example projects](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/), here are some that include ServiceStack + ASP.NET .Core MVC:

- [Mvc](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Mvc)
- [SimpleAuth.Mvc](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/SimpleAuth.Mvc)
- [RazorRockstars](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/RazorRockstars)
- [Hello/Mvc](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Hello/tree/master/src/Mvc)